# Using if in onMapReady callback make problem?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, polyline

I am working on a project that using google map and recently i faced an unreasonable problem .

Here is my onMapReady callback :

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    gmap = googleMap;

    stakeLine();   //number 1

    if (stakeMode) {

        if (bundle != null) {

            selectedLines = (List<LineDM>) bundle.getSerializable("lines");
            stakeLine();  //number 2
        }
        stakeMode = false;
    }

}
```

In stakeLine() function i draw some  polylines on map .

The problem is when i call  stakeLine() function in number1 place (as i show in code)  every thing is fine but when i call it from number2 place its not working . it goes to function but not drawing any thing ?

Any idea ?

Comment: ok then paste then content of stakeLine()

Comment: The two polylines may be the same

Comment: in stakeLine() funcction i only draw simple polyline . i do not call stakeLine() function two time i call it once in number2 position but when i see it is not working there for test i call it in number11 position and i see it is working 
@TaQuangTu

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your condition is satisfied or not,
also, put some Logs (such as "Log.d()" method ) in your StakeLine method to see if it's called .
as well, use debug tools to trace your code. 
aside from debug, you can use other methods of Google Map to check your drawn polyLine correctness.